# What is the use of RefreshItems() from Listbox in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

In winforms c#, there is a control named **ListBox**. It has a method **RefreshItems()**

What is the real use of this method ? can someone explain with example and sample code ?

Comment: It is a method, not a property.  It is *protected*, so you can't call it directly.  It is useful when the listbox is databound and the binding source or display item is changed.  It is exposed because the CheckedListBox control needs it as well.

Comment: It sends a [LB_RESETCONTENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lb-resetcontent) message to the Win32 Control, then, if the ListBox is bound to a DataSource, resets the data from the DataManager or generates a new array, then restores the state of each previously selected item(s) (if `SelectionMode != None`) and also resets the previous position. (I.e., it clears the List, rebinds with a new ObjectCollection and restores state)

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation it does the following:

> Refreshes all ListBox items and retrieves new strings for them.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.refreshitems?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Which is a bit vague.
If we look at the `RefreshItem(Int32)` method, it has a remark which clears things up a bit

> If the DisplayMember property is set and the property in the data source that is assigned to DisplayMember changes, use the RefreshItem method to update the value in the ListBox control.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.refreshitems?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

This suggests that if you've set a display to an item, and update the display string, you want to call the `RefreshItem` so that the UI will show the correct value.

`RefreshItems` is the same, but for *all* items.